# Merge ontologies using logmap

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, rdfs

I am trying to merge two diffrent ontologies with help of logmap software anyone please guide me.

Please provide me tutorial regard using of logmap software.

Thanks
Regards,
Bob

Comment: Hi @Bob, and welcome to StackOverflow. I think you're new here so you possibly don't know this, but this kind of question (asking for tutorials or other resources) is considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Instead you should try and explain your problem, show what you've done sofar, and where you're stuck. For more info on how to ask good questions here, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

That question is out of scope for Stackoverflow!

And using a search engine lead me to [the project page][1] which itself links to its [Github page][2] which itself contains a link to the [mailing list][3] for LogMap.

Moreover, the standalone distribution contains a README file which contains, among others,

> USAGE FROM APPLICATIONS:
>
> ...
>
> USAGE FROM COMMAND LINE:
>
> ...

I'm wondering, why you haven't been able to find the same by simply going to its project page and read things and documentation written there?

Comment: Instead of providing this as an answer, you should perhaps just vote to close, or if you can't (I think you need 3,000 rep to do that) leave a comment below the question and/or downvote.

Comment: because i am new in  this field.

Comment: i am trying to do it with protege 5.1 software. i read the guideline but confused then i post the questions here.

Comment: that's information not contained in your question. and I'm not aware of a Protege plugin, so how to you want to do this?